# Case to case inheritance

Tags: scala

Let's say I had an ordinary tree:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T]

case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) 
           extends Tree[T] {
  override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}

case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
    override def toString = "."
}
```

And tons of code that is already relying on that tree and uses `Node` in pattern matching.

Then I decided that I need a positional Node, for just one separate functionality:

```
case class PositionedNode[+T](val value: T, val left: Tree[T], val right: Tree[T], x: Int, y: Int)
     extends Tree[T] {
  override def toString = s"T[$x, $y]($value $left $right)"
}
```

I want the newly generated tree based on `PositionedNode` to work with my new code and with the old code. I do not want to change the old code or the original definition as it simply too much work.

My first intention was to inherit it from `Node`, but I cannot do that because of case-to-case inheritance restrictions. If I inherit it from `Tree`, it won't work with my old code

I've tried to search this on SO, but I found no answer that satisfies this problem. What is the preferable method to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My typical approach to such problem is to refactor target `case class` to `trait`, mimicking the old behaviour while renaming original `case class`:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T]

sealed abstract class Node[+T] extends Tree[T] {
  def value: T
  def left: Tree[T]
  def right: Tree[T]
}

//renamed from Node
case class SimpleNode[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T])
  extends Node[T] {
  override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}

case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
  override def toString = "."
}

case class PositionedNode[+T](val value: T, val left: Tree[T], val right: Tree[T], x: Int, y: Int)
  extends Node[T] {
  override def toString = s"T[$x, $y]($value $left $right)"
}

object Node {
  def apply[T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) = SimpleNode(value, left, right)
  def unapply[T](node: Tree[T]): Option[(T, Tree[T], Tree[T])] = node match {
    case SimpleNode(v, l, r) ⇒ Some((v, l, r))
    case PositionedNode(v, l, r, _, _) ⇒ Some((v, l, r))
    case _ ⇒ None
  }
}
```

Methods like `copy` need additonal treatment here, there is no universal solution in situation when they are widely used

Comment: This is probably the biggest issue in scala I've seen so far. I'd like it still to be done simpler, but to be honest I did expect for it to be much more ugly, you solution is somewhat beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: @Archeg I think whole `case class` idiom could be replaced with macro-implemented generators one day with more nifty control of what should and what should not be generated.